# Assign php function to an object created dynamically

Tags: php, javascript, function, append, inheritance

I have a php function which autocompletes an input of my websit, which i call it through jquery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){                      
        $('#concept_input').autocomplete({source:'search_Concept.php', minLength:1});   
    });
```

By the other side, I have a javascript function which adds a new input below the original one.

```
function addRow(tableID) {

            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);


            var cell3 = row.insertCell(0);
            var element3 = document.createElement("input");
            element3.type = "text";
            element3.id = "concept_input"
            element3.name = "concept_input";

            cell3.appendChild(element3);
}
```

My problem is that I can't find a way to pass the php function to the new inputs that are created with the javascript
I hope someone could help me, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID's should be unique.

I would do this (my changes noted with comments):

```
function addRow(tableID) {

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        //determine the existing inputs with the name concept_input
        var inputs = $('input[name="concept_input"]')

        var cell3 = row.insertCell(0);
        var element3 = document.createElement("input");
        element3.type = "text";

        //give the item a unique ID
        element3.id = "concept_input_" + inputs.length  
        element3.name = "concept_input";

        cell3.appendChild(element3);

         //use jQuery to add the autocomplete, just like you do at document ready.
         $('#concept_input_' + inputs.length).autocomplete({source:'search_Concept.php', minLength:1});
}
```